# WP7.1: How to open inbox (native to the device) by code

Tags: windows-phone-7, email, inbox

I'm working on register section with a function when user register successful it will navigate to a page with "open email" button - this button will open inbox of user's email on device.
I did some research but no luck i cannot find any useful article about this.
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: As you can't start apps within another Windows Phone 7 app, I don't believe there is a hack/work around to achieve this feature. Also the inbox is protected from 3rd party applications http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/84981/84981.aspx

Comment: oh men, sad to hear that is true :(
btw, thanks ajmccal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst you cannot navigate your customer to their inbox, you can guide them through the [creation of an email](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394003%28v=vs.92%29) using the [`EmailComposeTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.emailcomposetask%28v=vs.92%29).

If you're instead trying to get them to read an email from you (apart from considering that they *may* have registered with an email address they don't have configured on the phone; or they *may* have several inboxes to choose from), then you may want to slightly rethink your workflow -- perhaps allow use of the application, or transfer whatever token you'd need back to the phone as part of your registration process.